# ds4drv: Can you map multiple values to a single Linux input event?

Tags: input, games

I am using ds4drv ([git](https://github.com/chrippa/ds4drv)) to remap controller buttons to keyboard keys.

I want to map multiple controller buttons (referred to as values in .conf example: [ds4drv.conf](https://github.com/chrippa/ds4drv/blob/master/ds4drv.conf)) to a single Linux input event, e.g.:

```
KEY_X = button_cross
KEY_X = button_circle
```

However, when I do the above I get:

```
While reading from 'ds4drv.conf' [line 92]: option 'key_x' in section 'mapping:keyboard' already exists
```

How do I map two buttons to the same linux input event?

**OS:**

NAME="Linux Mint"

VERSION="21.1 (Vera)"